# ZSH agnoster Theme in VS-Code integrated terminal not displaying Symbols

Tags: zsh, visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh

I’m trying to pimp my VS Code integrated terminal with the agnoster theme and I ran into a small problem. It installed but the symbols are not shown correctly and the arrow at the end of the color bar is cut off. Also the text font is all stretched out too far. How do I fix this? I can't attach a screen shot illustrating the problem due to reputation points...

Cheers!

Answer (score 30):

Try putting this line in your settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Meslo LG S for Powerline'",
```

This will make vscode use the correct font family

Comment: Weird, that doesn't work for me... I have to use "MesloLGS NF"

Comment: @DrumM thank you! It works for me on Kubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Worked for my ubuntu 23, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

What you need to do is set

`"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": <YOUR_ZSH_FONT_NAME>`

To whatever font you have in your zsh settings:
[image]

So, for my own settings I added:

`"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF"`

Answer (score 12):

I had the mentioned problem in the VS Code integrated terminal on MacOS:
[image: Symbols not displayed]

I fixed it using `Monaco, PowerlineSymbols` in the user settings of VS Code.

You can fix this by either editing the
`$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
by adding/setting `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Monaco, PowerlineSymbols"`

or directly in the VS Code settings via `Code -> Preferences -> Settings` by searching there for `terminal integrated font`. Just add `Monaco, PowerlineSymbols` into the `Terminal > Integrated: Font Family` text input box.

Comment: Adding the `Monaco` font did not display correctly for me at first (because the font is not installed on ubuntu by default). Ubuntu users can use the `Ubuntu Mono` and `PowerlineSymbols` font instead.

Answer (score 5):

## Add this to your VSCode settings.json editor by pressing F1 and go to setting

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'RobotoMono Nerd Font', 'PowerlineSymbols'"
```

### Note: If you haven't installed one of the above fonts then this won't work.

Comment: Another example, which worked for me:
    `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'PowerlineSymbols'",
    "terminal.external.linuxExec": "gnome-terminal"`

Answer (score 5):

Above answers works specially of @fose, adding up few more details so in case any newbie face this can easily solve the problem. for complete guide check this [link](https://linuxhint.com/install_zsh_shell_ubuntu_1804/)

You need to download fonts first to solve this,
for **Power Line fonts** clone this fonts from github

> git clone https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline.git

after that you need to move this fonts to your Fonts folder that could be used globally.

> sudo mv Menlo*.ttf /usr/share/fonts

if you face any error in this, you can manually type the name of Fonts, e.g

> sudo mv 'Menlo Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf' /usr/share/fonts

after all this, open VS Code

VS Code Settings `-> Preferences -> Settings` 
Search for `terminal integrated font` or `Font Family` and select Terminal.
Add `Monaco, PowerlineSymbols` into the `Terminal > Integrated: Font Family` in text input box.

END RESULT: including settings
[image: END RESULT image]

Answer (score 3):

this work for me on WSL 1 , windows 10
here it's before
[image]

open vs code you can press F1 and type setting.json
and add {
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'RobotoMono Nerd Font', 'PowerlineSymbols' , 'Hack Nerd Font'"
}

here is a link for [RobotoMono Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/RobotoMono/Regular/complete/Roboto%20Mono%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf)

here is a link for [PowerlineSymbols](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/src/glyphs/PowerlineSymbols.otf)

here is a link for [Hack Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Hack/Regular/complete)

then restart vs code and it will work just fine

here it's after

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MesloLGS NF worked for me just you need to check terminal preferences font which is installed that you have to use.

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me. What I ended up doing that worked (on the Mac)

1. Install the Powerline/Agnoster font that you want
2. In VSCode, open Terminal and list the fonts available by running:

   $ system_profiler -json SPFontsDataType | grep "family | sort | uniq
3. Find the Powerline font (and copy exactly what the title of the font is). For me, this was: 'Meslo LG S for Powerline'.
4. Add the exact title (in single quotes) to the Terminal Fonts (or terminal.integrated.fontFamily in the settings.json)

And done! The terminal should change almost immediately.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, after trying all the others (I'm on Mac too). Thanks a lot for this very clear answer!